# python decorator equivalent in php

Tags: php, python, decorator, python-decorators

I'd like to replicate aspect oriented programming in php

Assuming I have something like this:

```
def wrapper(func):
   print ("start")
   func()
   print ("end")

@wrapper
def hello():
   print ("hello")
```

What's the equivalent in php ?

Comment: Would that be a delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of Go! AOP framework and can tell you that there is no direct equivalent of Python decorators in PHP, because in PHP all classes are closed. This means there are no runtime changes for methods and classes without special extensions such as Runkit or PHP-AOP.
Without that you can use decorators or proxies with additional logic, or alternatively install Go! framework that can automatically create decorators for your original classes. This will be great option if you have a big project, for example, enterprise apps